# C# check if directory exists in azure storage

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to see if a directory exists within azure data storage. This is how I am initializing the service client:

```
 private void InitializeServiceClient(IndesignExportConfiguration exportConfig, String rootContainer)
        {//"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
            serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(exportConfig.BlobConnectionString);
            flyersContainerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(rootContainer.ToLower());
        }
```

And this is where I am trying to see if the directory exists:

```
     var rootContainerName = dealNo + "/";
            _flyerId = flyerId;
            var blobClient = flyersContainerClient.GetBlobClient(rootContainerName);
            
            if (blobClient.Exists())
            {
                await ListBlobsForPrefixRecursive(flyersContainerClient, rootContainerName, 1);
            }                
            else
            {
                InitializeServiceClient(_exportConfig, _exportConfig.SecondaryRootContainer);
                await ListBlobsForPrefixRecursive(flyersContainerClient, rootContainerName, 1);
            }
```

So far I have asked another question on stackoverflow and I was told that because the directory is virtual my blobclient.exists if statement wont work. I then looked into using the following:

```
var blobDirectory = flyersContainerClient.GetBlobDirectoryReference("Path_to_dir");
bool directoryExists = blobDirectory.ListBlobs().Count() > 0
```

and this:

```
bool directoryExists = flyersContainerClient.ListBlobsWithPrefix("DirectoryA/DirectoryB/").Count() > 0
```

Unforutnately the methods `GetBlobDirectoryReference` and `ListBlobsWithPrefix` dont seem to exist. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong, or which assembly reference  I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question looks really similar, but uses different SDK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125304/listing-blob-by-prefix-in-cloudblobdirectory-object